# Easy way to access req.body in express?

Tags: node.js

I'm just going to ask:

Is there any surefire way to ALWAYS get data that's in req.body, in nodejs/express?  I really hate working with it (it's not exactly like $_POST in PHP).

Thanks.

Comment: could you show us some code or?

Comment: you could use body parser module as a middleware with express.

Comment: https://github.com/netsider/facemash-clone/blob/master/index.js Would be the code I'm working on, but that version currently works (I didn't commit the version that wasn't).  Just from my code you can probably tell I'm having trouble reading the object, though (on the /transmitPlayerData route).

Comment: Actually, this view, along with that file above, are giving me problems:
https://github.com/netsider/facemash-clone/blob/master/views/node-dopple-main-wrong.ejs (It works and I can access the request object when using the submit buttons, but not the pictures with the same data attributes)

Comment: Here is a permanent (at least for the foreseeable future) version of index.js, in case I edit the one above:
https://github.com/netsider/facemash-clone/blob/master/index-working.js

I'll keep both up for a while.

Comment: Also, just wanted to clarify that /transmitPlayerData isn't where I'm having the problem.  I' having the problem on /submitPlayer when using the images as submit buttons (just so nobody gets confused, if someone does happen to look at it).

Answer (score 0):

just add `app.use(express.json());`

Now you can access your req.body always without any external package, but make sure you are having a post route handler to access it (that is data should be sent to your node/express)

see this for [more](https://codewithhugo.com/parse-express-json-form-body/)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.post(
  '/test',
  (req, res) => res.json(req.body)
)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

OR

If it doesn't solve ,then Problem is in the front end, ensure your forms and input(THE PLACE YOU ARE TAKING USER INPUT), it should be `post and text` respectively FOR **FORM TAG AND INPUT TAG**

Comment: I posted my code in the question comments.  I've been using that, though (well, app.use(bodyParser.json()), anyway).

Comment: Earlier versions of Express used to have a lot of middleware bundled with it. bodyParser was one of the middlewares that came it. When Express 4.0 was released they decided to remove the bundled middleware from Express and make them separate packages instead. The syntax then changed from app.use(express.json()) to app.use(bodyParser.json()) after installing the bodyParser module.

bodyParser was added back to Express in release 4.16.0. That means you don't have to use bodyParser.json() anymore if you are on the latest release. You can use express.json() instead.

Comment: Updated my answer please check, if it helped upvote it so that, it can help others.

Comment: I included/replaced that part, and it's still producing the same error.  The problem doesn't seem to be with index.js, but with my .ejs file.  I posted both in the comments, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: The data/body portion of the request object is either undefined or empty a lot of the time and I have no idea why -- that's the main problem I'm having, personally.

Comment: Problem is in the front end, ensure  your forms and input(THE PLACE YOU ARE TAKING USER INPUT, it should be post and text respectively FOR FORM TAG AND INPUT TAG

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the body-parser. As you've explained in the comments

> I'm having the problem on /submitPlayer when using the images as
> submit buttons [...]

you are submitting the form using image-inputs, i.e.

```
<form action="/submitPlayer" method="POST">
  <input type="image" height="<%= playerOneImgHeight %>px" width="<%= newImgWidth %>px" src="<%= playerOneImage %>" name="playerName" value="<%= playerOneIsWinnerArray %>">
```

An `input type="image"` sets an image as the submit button and is not an input field that can carry values to the server (your essentially submitting an empty form, hence `req.body` is empty). Fix your form and add the data you want to send using e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="tbd" name="tbd">
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: But I want the user to be able to click one of two images to submit the form.  Your way isn't really a solution to that, but yeah, I realized that's where my problem was.  I still don't know how to fix it by making the user able to click the images to select their choice, though.

Comment: I can get everything working by using a hidden field, too, but what's the answer to getting it so the user can submit the form via two images?  Is a separate ajax request the only way, or is there a way to do it via HTML forms?

Comment: You can still have the image-inputs - they act as submit buttons. So you can have those image-inputs and hidden input fields to carry the actual data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image explains it quite well.

Comment: but then the images mean nothing when you click on them, unlike a button (since the hidden field values stay the same each time).